# How to find all unused APIs of library in project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to find all unused public APIs of my library in another app. This library is imported as an external library. I tried to do it via code analysis, but I ended up finding unused methods in my app.

I've created a search scope for menu Code->Inspect code... But that gave me nothing.

Since this library has hundreds of public methods, that's sad to check it manually.

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: why you need to do thta? proguard should strip all unneeded code when you build release APK

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, this app is testing the library. I want to find untested (currently unused) APIs to add to the app.

Comment: Quick hack would be simply to run tests with coverage - then you will clearly see not walked code

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, it's not testing like with tests, the app just uses APIs. So there's no way to see if something is wrong after build or tests.